# Setting up a Git repository under Review-Board on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, git, windows-server-2003, msysgit, review-board

I need some help.

I have a **Windows Server 2003** computer that I'm setting up with **Git** and **Review-Board**.

My Git repositories are managed by **Gitolite**. The setup is successful and everything is working fine (tested with multiple workstations).

The Review-Board site has installed successfully and is hosted under **Apache 2.2**. This is also working fine in itself (the website is accessible and responds for workstations), except the part where I'm trying to link Git repositories to Review-Board.

Most tutorials (example: http://ericholscher.com/blog/2011/jan/24/using-reviewboard-git/) provide good details on how to setup a Git repository under Review-Board, except that they refer to Linux/Unix systems, and I am running Windows Server 2003.

My Gitolite repositories are stored under `D:\Repositories\Git`
Example: `D:\Repositories\Git\sdu-test\.git`

My understanding is that Review-Board needs a local clone of the repository(ies). Therefore, I created a directory named `LocalClones` and I cloned my repository.
Example: `D:\Repositories\LocalClones\`***[I cloned sdu-test.git here]***
Command used (from LocalClones directory): `git clone ../Git/sdu-test.git`
(the clone was successful)

Now, in Review-Board, I'm trying to declare my *sdu-test* repository.

- Name is '`sdu-test`'
- Hosting type is '`Custom`'
- Repository type is '`Git`'
- Path is '`D:\Repository\LocalClones\sdu-test`' (I have also tried with '`sdu-test.git`', and '`sdu-test/.git`')
- Mirror path is '`ssh://git@localhost/sdu-test`' (I have also tried simply '`git@localhost:sdu-test`', and no mirror path at all)

When I click ***Save***, I get the following error: ***(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')***. I have no idea what to do about that.

If I try to change the path to a Unix-style path ('`/D/Repository/LocalClones/sdu-test`'), I get a different error message: `Permission denied accessing the local Git repository '/D/Repository/LocalClones/sdu-test'`. With a Unix-style path, I could even write a directory path that doesn't exist ('`/I/Dont/Exist`') and the same permission denied error is returned (the path in the error message does reflect the change though).

Can anyone help me out and tell me how to declare my local Git repository in Review-Board under Windows?

Thank you very much!

** UPDATE ** thank you Tamagochi and VonC for your answers, but unfortunately they're not working for me. Even after fixing the git.py file, I still get the `Permission denied accessing the local Git repository '/D/Repository/LocalClones/sdu-test'` error message.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug in ReviewBoard 1.5.5 that causes this error. You can resolve this problem in either of two ways:

1. Move your repositories to drive C.
2. Edit `\reviewboard\scmtools\git.py` file, and replace the following line:

   ```
   self.git_dir = url_parts[2]
   ```

   with:

   ```
   self.git_dir = url_parts[1] + url_parts[2]
   ```

   Then use the following path: `file://D:/Repository/LocalClones/sdu-test`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with ReviewBoard, but from what I can gather (from [your link](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/management/repositories/#git)):

- you do need to put the full path up to the `.git` directory of the local clone.
- you should make your local clone through an url-based address. If the local file protocol is to be used, you should try with `file///D/Repository/LocalClones/sdu-test`.
  `git@localhost:sdu-test` would only work if you have a git daemon running.
  `ssh://git@localhost/sdu-test` would only work if you have a ssh daemon running.